# How can I set default font in matplotlib to Helvetica?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, fonts

I'm trying to set up the default font for all of my figures by modifying my rc parameters. But I am getting an error.

I tried the following code to modifying my rc file --

```
dill.load_session('./param_new_EVI5_n1_design_2.pkl')

font = {'family' : 'sans-serif',
        'sans-serif':'Helvetica',
        'weight' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 18}

plt.rc('font', **font)
```

However, I'm getting the following error --

> /home/shihab/.conda/envs/paper1_py37/lib/python3.7/site->packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1241: UserWarning: findfont: Font >family ['sans-serif'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.
>    (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))

Comment: The problem is the missing Helvetica font on your system. [This](https://github.com/olgabot/sciencemeetproductivity.tumblr.com/blob/master/posts/2012/11/how-to-set-helvetica-as-the-default-sans-serif-font-in.md) post explains how to set it up for matplotlib

Comment: Will it work for Ubuntu? The post seems to be for OS X.